# Why is my RubyGems environment different when using setuid from an upstart script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, upstart

I'm having a problem where my RubyGems environment is wrong when starting a Rails application from Upstart on Ubuntu. In my Upstart script I use `setuid www`, then run a wrapper script which eventually starts Puma.

From the command line, as user `www`, the output of `gem env` is what I expect:

```
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/2.5.0
     - /home/www/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
     - /usr/share/rubygems-integration/2.5.0
     - /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all
```

If I run `gem env` from the Upstart script, after setting `setuid www`, I get this:

```
  - GEM PATHS:
    - /var/lib/gems/2.5.0
    - /.gem/ruby/2.5.0
    - /usr/share/ruby
```

This causes gems to be installed in the wrong place, or to not be found because they were installed with `--user-install` putting them in `/home/www/.gem/`.

For now, I can explicitly set `$GEM_HOME` and `$GEM_PATH` but it would be cleaner to just rely on the default RubyGems environment for the `www` user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `$HOME` is not being set in the Upstart script ;)

Add `env HOME=/home/www` to the upstart script and `gem env` will output the expected environment settings.